# phpunit hangs in phpstorm on 58th test

Tags: phpstorm

Whenever I run phpunit in PHPStorm, everything goes fine until the 58th test. As soon as I hit the 58th test, the script just hangs. When I use only the phpunit binary everything works fine. Has anybody seen this or know of a reason why this would be happening?

Comment: did you manage to solve that? Otherwise, have you got some more info, like version number etc.?

Comment: I reported the issue to PHPStorm, it was related to running tests in separate process. I gave them the information they wanted as well as a basic setup that would replicate the issue. I think I was missing some information and they closed the ticket.